# How to set the size of a drawable?

Tags: android

The android developer docs say that the size for an icon in the action bar should be **32x32 dp**. I have an xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/my_pic1"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

How can I make the size of **my_pic1** 32x32dp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to specify explicit size here, you just need to put correct drawable image in correct folder. You can download launcher icons from [Here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) and put drawables according to their resolution in respective folders.

Comment: Thank you, you have been a big help.